# Unable to make a MARKET order on Spot Test Network on Binance. Empty JSON is returned

Tags: binance

I’m trying to test **MARKET** order with **Spot Test Network** in Postman. But I receive empty JSON as response.

Why? Do MARKET orders work on **Spot Test Network** as of July 2020? Was my order executed? How can I check on **Spot Test Network** if a MARKET order was executed?

My order params:

```
symbol: BTCUSDT
side: BUY
type: MARKET
quantity: 0.1
timestamp: {{timestamp}}
signature: {{signature}}
```

But the response is just an empty JOSN:

```
{}
```

Why?
What do I do wrong?
How to fix?

cURL code for your convenience. Just replace {TIMESTAMP}, (SIGNATURE} and {YOUR_API_KEY} with your real ones:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/order/test?symbol=BTCUSDT&side=BUY&type=MARKET&quantity=0.1&timestamp={TIMESTAMP}&signature={SIGNATURE}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'X-MBX-APIKEY: {YOUR_API_KEY}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out what was the problem.

Change

```
POST https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/order/test
```

to

```
POST https://testnet.binance.vision/api/v3/order
```

The endpoint ending `/test` is for testing, which means the backend will check all parameters and return empty json if it passed all validations. Otherwise `400` will be returned along with with error messages.